# Web deployment task failed - Issue when connecting to remote server from local machine

Tags: visual-studio-2012, amazon-ec2, msdeploy

I was trying to publish a web application to remote server (amazon windows server 2012) using Visual Studio 2012. Following is the error I am getting.

***Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("amazon-server-name"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.***

I did go through several articles mentioning this issue. Also both the web management service and web deployment agent service is running on remote machine. Also in IIS’s management service part I did enable the remote connection. When try to deploy a website from server machine itself, it’s working. But from my local machine to windows server it’s showing error like cannot connect to remote server. Anyone has any clue on how to solve this issue?

Note: Microsoft Web Deploy tool 3.5 is running on both server and the local machine.

Looking forward.

Comment: `I did go through several articles mentioning this issue` : citation required. Some reference just assume that you know how to open port in Security group.  You must show what you have diagnose so far!

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try just using FTP in Visual Studio? You mentioned "web project", I know some Visual Studio things are iffy with connecting to web servers. Just try a simple FTP into the server, then you should be able to save/test/deploy projects and files that way.

If you're still having problems, there's just an unlimited amount of problems that could cause this (hence why I don't work on Windows servers anymore). Could be ports, firewalls, security settings, folder permissions, user privileges, any combination of things. Good luck.